# Number with same digit sum of only ones in multiple bases

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$, $k$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ be positive integers.

Does there exist $k$ such that

- There are exactly $n$ ones in it.
- There are any number of zeroes in it.
- There exists no digit but zeroes and ones.

whether written in number system of base $a_1$ or base $a_2$?

Note that $n$ has constant value, so both representations must have same number of ones. Also, the conditions will always be met for base $2$, so most likely $a_1=2$.

If no, is there a simple proof? If yes, is there a generalized method for finding such numbers, and have they been studied before?

Comment: Do you mean that $n$ and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are fixed numbers, if we take $n=2$ and $k=(101)_2=(11)_4$ so it fits the conditions, or do you mean that the $n$ is fixed and we are looking for a number $k$ which have $n$ ones in all bases? I think it's better to remove "$k$" in the first sentence "let$\cdots$".

Comment: Let $a,b,n$ be positive integers such that $a<b$.The set of integers $S(a,b,n)$ which have exactly $n$ number of ones in both the  base $a$ and in the base $b$.$$S(a,a^m,n)=\left\{\sum_{i\in A}a^{im} / A\subset \mathbb{N}, \#(A)=n\right\}$$, and if $k \in S(a,b,n)$ is equivalent to solving an equation of the form:$$a^{i_1}+\cdots+a^{i_n}=b^{j_1}+\cdots+b^{j_n} $$ and this for $n=2$ $a=2;b=3$ gives $2^x+2^y=3^u+3^v$ which i suspect it's very hard to generalize.

Comment: @Elaqqad Yes, $101_2=11_4$ is a solution, and I found a few others as well. I don't know the notation which you have used. Are you saying that there is no simple method to find such numbers? Anyways, you could post this as an answer, and get upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b,n$ be positive integers such that $a<b$. We use the notation $S(a,b,n)$ for the set of integers which have exactly $n$ number of ones in both the base $a$ and in the base $b$ and no other digits. as a first observation we have :
$$S(a,a^m,n)=\left \{\sum_{i∈A}a^{im} \Big /A\subset \mathbb{N},\#(A)=n\right \}$$
(The sum is taken over all elements in $\#(A)$ denotes the cardinal of $A$)

Now if we return to the definition, finding an element $k\in S(a,b,n)$ is equivalent to solving an exponential Diophantine equation of the form:
$$a^{i_1}+⋯+a^{i_n}=b^{j_1}+⋯+b^{j_n}\\ i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_n\\
j_1<j_2<\cdots<j_n$$
As an example,for $n=2, a=2,b=3$ the equation to solve is 
$$2^x+2^y=3^u+3^v$$

this equation have a solution which is $(2,3,1,2)$? Equations of this form are not always easy to solve and in particular when we deal with the same bases I mean there is $n$ powers of $a$ and $n$ powers of $b$, the very known useful too is eﬃcient congruencing method which can very helpful to solve a lot of equations, But if we return to your question we know that (using only congruence methods):

> **Theorem** $(1)$ : Let p, q be distinct odd primes such that $q = 1 \mod p$. Then the equation
>    $$p^a + p^b = q^c + q^d$$
>   have the only trivial solution.

which signifies $S(p,q,2)=\emptyset $ in this case, this implies that there are some cases for $n$ where there is no $k$ which verifies your question. we can also prove easily that $S(a,ab,n)=\emptyset $ using some elementary divisibility problems , And in general one can study this set and deduce some properties using only elementary methods.

$(1)$ PACIFIC JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS Vol. 101, No. 2, 1982
EXPONENTIAL DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS
J. L. BRENNER AND LORRAINE L. FOSTER